# Updating Points

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, highcharts

I am implementing graph in my `Projec`t.
Now i am stuck at a point, where i want the points in graph to be updated using table and vice-versa.

I have made a **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HgtS9/1/)**

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where is the table.. I couldnt find any table where i could insert the values in your fiddle

Comment: Scroll down in fiddle, you will Table ranging from 10%-100% with X and Y axis.Then click on any column it will get editable

Comment: @NidhinSG would you guys please communicate in English :)

Comment: @Richa I didnt have a good look at your code.. But i think 
$(".cellEditing").change(function() {
//get tablevalues;
//pass it to the update graph function;
});

Comment: @NidhinSGWould you please help it out in fiddle :)

Comment: For me, jsfiddle seems to be down.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Can you please retry it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made one fiddle.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhinsg/HgtS9/15/)

I have added one function updater

```
function updater(yv,xv) {
    switch(xv) {
        case "0.00":
            console.log("A");
            $("#bb").html(yv);
            $("tr: first").css("border","1px solid black");
            break;
    }
    console.log(yv+", "+xv);
}
```

go through the fiddle and you will understand what all changes i made.. Just drag the 0% of the graph and u can see the table geting updated. I havent changed for other table values.

Comment: @NidhinSG Any way now i can update Graph by changing value in table?? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Richa because i wrote it like that.. you can update it as per ur wish.. :)

Comment: @NidhinSG I tried but unable to update Y axis as well. Please help me out, i am newbie in coding :(

Comment: $("#bb").html(yv);
here yv has your y value.
did you check the changes made in html..
I gave aa id to the first table and bb id to the second table
so use id aa to change x and bb to change y

Comment: you have to provide id to all tr like i did in first two..then it will be easy for you to update..

Comment: @NidhinSG Yup thanks. But any idea how do i change points in graph if i enter value in table

Comment: @Richa on $("#bb").change(function() {}); try to pass the first variable of ur data array as $("#bb").html();

Comment: @NidhinSG A liitle demo in fiddle please:( Then will try to do rest.And what is 0.00 in switch???

Comment: Do you know to use console? Then it will be easy for you to understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51860/discussion-between-richa-and-nidhin-s-g)

Comment: @user3513687 pne solve aai.. more dan dat.. :P :D aale vilichu kooti natikathadi

Comment: @NidhinSG ente kadama njn nirvahikande.... gmail vare okke ethiyallo karyangal.. :D B-)